# Access denied for users from domainB, domainA users has no issues

Tags: trusted-domain

I am using SP2010. We have a mysite webapplication (http://sp2010-mysites.mycompany.net). All users from domainA has permissions to this webapplication. When you go to the people search 
 and search on some user and click on the user you go to the mysite webapplication. For example I clicked on the user "abcd", I come on this site:

http://sp2010-mysites.mycompany.net/Person.aspx?accountname=DOMAINA\abcd

But we have buyed another company. They are using domainB. This domain is also available in the peoplepicker. When a user search on "abcd" they see the user. When they click on the user they get access denied. I give this user access "Read" permissions on the site collection "http://sp2010-mysites.mycompany.net". It doesnt help. I add this user to the site collection administrators. It didnt help. I add this user to the webapplication policy in Central Admin with full control. It didnt help.

I think it is some trust which needs to be configured between 2 differant domains. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Might need to resolve accounts across multiple forests. Multiple log-on forest deployments are described in this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd279546(v=office.14).aspx) . Will come in handy as it explains its used on organization mergers.